# Styled compoenents/emotion: add a style object to apply to different components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I create different icons in Emotion (could be Styled Components as well), and I apply the exact styling to each icon:

```
const BellIcon = styled(Bell)`
  width: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  height: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  flex-shrink: 0;
`;

const PlayIcon = styled(Play)`
  width: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  height: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  flex-shrink: 0;
`;

const RefreshIcon = styled(Refresh)`
  width: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  height: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  flex-shrink: 0;
`;
```

Is there a way to to outsource the styling into an object and apply the same styles to each icon using the object? (or another method? Just so the code isn't repetitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the "css" function from "styled-components" to group styles in an object.

Like this:

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';

const GroupedStyles = css`
  width: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  height: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
  flex-shrink: 0;
`;

const RefreshIcon = styled(Refresh)`
  ${GroupedStyles};
`;

const PlayIcon = styled(Play)`
  ${GroupedStyles};
`;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer this works but I cannot get access to my props, would you know how can I get access to them?

Comment: Nvm I can just use the theme object directly without the props thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your icon components are SVGs, I'd do the following:

```
const IconWrapper = styled.div`
  svg {
    width: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
    height: ${(props) => props.theme.sizes.iconDimension};
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
`;
```

And then use it as:

```
<IconWrapper>
  <Icon />
</IconWrapper>
```